# get wrong epc on MIPS

Tags: mips, cpu-registers

I know MIPS would get wrong epc register value when it happens at branch delay, and epc = fault_address - 4.
But now, I often get the wrong EPC value which is even NOT in .text segment such as 0xb6000000, what's wrong with the case??
Thanks for your advance..

Comment: Your code branched to that location?

Comment: @markgz, my code should not jmp to address which even in .text range.

Comment: @markgz my code should not jmp to address which even in .text range.
consider such a case: jal v1, if v1 value is a fault address, then what's the epc value? epc=v1 or epc=address of instruction:"jal v1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU does not know anything about the boundaries of the `.text` region in your program. It simply implements a 2^32 byte address space.

It is possible for an incorrectly  programmed jump to go to any address within the 2^32 byte address space. The jump instruction itself will not cause any sort of exception - in fact the *MIPS32® Architecture for Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32® Instruction Set* explicitly states that jump (`J, JR, JALR`) instructions do not trigger any exceptions.

When the processor starts executing from the destination of an incorrectly  programmed jump, in presumably uninitialized memory, what happens next depends on the contents of that memory. If uninitialized memory is filled with "random" data, that data will be interpreted as instructions which the processor will execute until an illegal instruction is found, or until an instruction triggers some other exception.

Comment: thanks for your explicit response.. jal 0x00000000<FUNCTIOIN>, then epc should be 0x00000000 when content of this memory address is illegal instruction, right?

Comment: Yes, the EPC should hold the address of the illegal instruction.